# Literature Stack is now open!

Tags: discussion

Okay, not precisely a question, but important to many here, I think.

http://literature.stackexchange.com is now in beta and already churning up questions. Given that we get quite a few "discussion of literary works" questions here — it's even one of the close reasons — I thought our community would be pleased to see a sibling site's birth and might perhaps wish to contribute.

Comment: I don't think anyone's going to ban you from here for mentioning it :o) BTW ... *Thanks for mentioning it!*

Comment: Meta is the right place for announcements. This is great, and glad to see :-)

Comment: That being said, Literature is currently in _private_ beta, which means people who aren't already in can't visit or contribute for a few weeks yet.

Comment: Please add Literature.SE (as well as Worldbuilding.SE) to the list under "This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network".

Comment: @ what yes, the minute it's open to the public, we should absolutely add both of those to the close/migrate options. @Standback, how do we make that happen?

Comment: I'll look into it.

Comment: Usually SE won't build in migration to a beta site, but maybe they'll make an exception for this one.  In general, they look at migration history -- how many questions does site A actually send to site B? -- in making their decisions.  I haven't reviewed our migration history lately, but mods have a view of this data that @Standback has probably found by now.

Comment: There's a back door into private betas: find the Area 51 page, use the "visit the site" link, and create an account from there.

Comment: Last I checked, we could only have one "standard" migration destination and that's the English site. But people can always vote to close and flag for mod attention, we'll send a question to the right place.

Comment: @MonicaCellio - The backdoor worked. I'm more lurking than posting, but it's interesting, nonetheless.

Comment: Officially in Public Beta now!  @Standback where's that close/migrate option?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thank you.

Thank you so much.

Comment: the place is *crankin'.* I have never seen so much activity in such a short time. O.o

Comment: Ah, but I won't be the best question answerer on there. Unlike a lot of writers who 'critique' or 'analyse' the book, I prefer to enjoy and imagine. In turn... I'm not the best at answering questions about symbolism, references, etc. unless I do an analysis on it @LaurenIpsum

Comment: C'mon over anyway! you don't have to be "the best" to be "good," or even "to have fun."